# Capture photo intent resultCode

Tags: java, android

How can I detect wether the user take picture and selects it (with the confirm button on camera) or they just turn on a camera, take a picture and remove it (with the cancel button on camera)

When the user take picture I am loading that picture into an ImageView. If user hits confirm button then everything is OK but if user don't want that picture and decide to hit cancel button then the `ImageView` goes blank.

This is my camera intent :

```
void capturePhoto() {
//        ImagePicker.pickImage(this, "Select your image:");

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(f);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
                pictureUri = null;
            }

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
```

And onActivityResult, in both cases the resultCode is always 1. (note that RESULT_OK is -1) and I dont know why.

This is how I set `image` to `ImageView` using Glide:

```
Glide.with(this).load(mCurrentPhotoPath).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Any Suggestions?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

you just need to pass if statement in onActivityresult
cause if you use directly that URI or whatever you use which has no any frame set cause user cancel it so just do as given

```
 //if needed than
//public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:

                   //do your stuff here
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is I use String mCurrentPhotoPath to set photo, not a bitmap. And resultCode is 1, not RESULT_OK. I dont know why

Comment: i forgot the declaration of result_ok check now

Comment: actually you dont have to declare that cause it is default value in activity you have to try first

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
 static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            if (isCameraPermissionEnabled()) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        1);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isCameraPermissionEnabled() {

        return !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            mBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),mBitmap));
        }
    }
```

//For more information https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: I take code from this site but I save the full-size photo. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath